# Error: Out of range value for column 'id' when using an after insert trigger in MySQL

Tags: mysql, triggers

I have a MySQL table named products with the following structure:

```
domain_id varchar(10),
data_source_id int(12),
id bigint(64),
title varchar(255)`
```

This table has an after insert trigger that inserts the values of `domain_id`, `data_source_id`, and id into a new table.

I'm attempting to insert a new record into the products table using the following query:

```
INSERT INTO products (domain_id, data_source_id, id, title) VALUES ("12345678", 123, 8083207880923, "test")
```

However, I encountered the error

> Out of range value for column 'id' at row 1.

As you can see this is the `BIGINT` column and the number "8083207880923"

is well within its range. Also, the error disappears when the trigger is removed.

I'm clueless and confused as to why this is happening. Any help or directions on this would be greatly helpful. Thanks in advance!!

DDL query for table products:

```
CREATE TABLE products (
    domain_id varchar(16) NOT NULL,
    data_sources_id int(12) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
    id bigint(64) NOT NULL,
    title varchar(255) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (domain_id, data_sources_id, id)
  );`
```

DDL query of the new table where the trigger is updating data:

```
CREATE TABLE products_process (
    id int(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT primary key,
    domain_id varchar(10) NOT NULL,
    data_sources_id int(10) NOT NULL,
    product_id varchar(20) NOT NULL,
    processed tinyint DEFAULT 0,
    created_at timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
  );
```

DDL query for trigger:

```
CREATE TRIGGER product_insert_trigger
  AFTER INSERT ON products
  FOR EACH ROW
  BEGIN
  INSERT INTO products_process (domain_id, data_sources_id, id)
  VALUES (NEW.domain_id, NEW.data_sources_id, NEW.id);
END;`
```

Comment: Perhaps you coud share the trigger's code with us so we can have a chance of figuring out what went wrong!

Comment: Please also share the ddl of all relevant tables

Comment: I have updated the requested details in the question. Thanks in advance!!

Comment: The `id` is an `auto_increment` , can you share the last used id?

Comment: 25 is the last used id

Comment: the trigger is attempting to write a bigint value of 8083207880923 to an unsigned datatype which has a max allowed value of 4294967295 the error is about the id in the products_processd table.

Comment: Thanks everyone  for you help!! it is resolved!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The id in the target table (`products_process`) of the trigger defined as `int(10)` and you try to insert the bigint to that.. That can't work.

Also this column is an `auto_increment`, you shouldn't set it by the trigger

Comment: There is also a typo in the insert statement and product_id  in the target table is not null but no value or default is provided. https://dbfiddle.uk/rSCvYJyM